# gradle parent pom like feature

Tags: gradle

At my work we use Maven. I am going to try gradle for the first time. We use a common parent pom for all project which has setting for commonly used maven plugins and few comon dependencies. Is there a similar option available in gradle?

My second question is regarding release management. We use maven release plugin, which works pretty good for us. Is there something similar available in Gradle?

Comment: This is what I do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21139778/859225

Hope this helps.

Comment: What did you end up doing? I have similar problem but I can't use maven BOM because the artifacts are being generated via a gradle project and if I use maven parent pom, it doesn't honor the downstream dependencies

Answer (score 34):

To share stuff within multiple projects of the same build, use `allprojects { ... }`, `subprojects { ... }`, etc. Also, extra properties (`ext.foo = ...`) declared in a parent project are visible in subprojects. A common idiom is to have something like `ext.libs = [junit: "junit:junit:4.11", spring: "org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.0.RELEASE", ...]` in the top-level build script. Subprojects can then selectively include dependencies by their short name. You should be able to find more information on this in the [Gradle Forums](http://forums.gradle.org).

To share logic across builds, you can either write a script plugin (`foo.gradle`), put it up on a web server, and include it in builds with `apply from: "http://..."`, or write a binary plugin (a class implementing `org.gradle.api.Plugin`), publish it as a Jar to a repository, and include it in builds with `apply plugin: ...` and a `buildscript {}` section. For details, see the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) and the many samples in the full Gradle distribution.

A current limitation of script (but not binary) plugins is that they aren't cached. Therefore, a build will only succeed if it can connect to the web server that's serving the plugin.

As to your second question (which should have been a separate question), there are a couple of third-party release plugins available, for example https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-release.

Comment: :-) Don't know if there is any other way. I thought it would be as simple as writing something like "extend my_parent_gradle_config_coordinates". Thanks for your help.

Comment: > To share stuff within multiple projects of the same build ... but 1) parent poms can (I would say should) also be used to define "organisation wide" build features and 2) I'd say you are better organising dependencies using composites (composite-testing, composite-spring etc).

Comment: for future reference, scripts downloaded from `apply from` [are now cached](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/1900)

Answer (score 15):

The [io.spring.dependency-management](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/23/better-dependency-management-for-gradle) plugin allows you to use a Maven bom to control your build's dependencies:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.3.RELEASE"
  }
}

apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
```

Next, you can use it to import a Maven bom:

```
dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.1.1.RELEASE'
  }
}
```

Now, you can import dependencies without specifying a version number:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-core'
}
```

Comment: Alternative to `io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin` is https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-dependency-recommender-plugin `com.netflix.nebula:nebula-dependency-recommender`. Also   ``org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin`` starting from version 1.3 uses
  ``io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin`` for dependeny management.

Comment: If using Gradle 5+, please use the platform concept and leave the spring plugin. As in `testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.6.0')` and `testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter')` See
https://gradle.org/whats-new/gradle-5/#bom-support

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do things like maven parent pom is to to use gradle "apply from". 
Something like this：

```
allprojects { // or: subprojects { ... }
    apply from: "gradle/script/common.gradle"
}
```

The link and be a related path or an URL. Hope it helps.

Reference:
[Import a Gradle script from the root into subprojects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307434/import-a-gradle-script-from-the-root-into-subprojects)
[Super POM, Parent POM type of hierarchy management in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136373/super-pom-parent-pom-type-of-hierarchy-management-in-gradle/21139778#21139778)

Answer (score 1):

I too wanted this type of feature, I have created a plugin to provide this here: https://github.com/boxheed/gradle-pater-build-plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the Parent pom content in to Gradle init file very easily.
Gradle init script provides same functionality as Maven super/parent pom. The basic difference is that you can call init script

Run time
   As many as of them This gives us flexibility to change the init
   script on run time but doubt of not tracking the changes.

You need to take repository, distribution management, profiling and other checks like findbugs, checkstyle etc in to init script.

The detail is huge, You can find complete information here by me.
http://www.scmtechblog.net/2015/12/how-to-migrate-parent-pom-from-maven-to.html

I have explained about gradle release plugin which is similar to maven release plugin.

Answer (score 0):

to achive your goal you could apply the concept of 'multiproject build' explained in the gradel user guide [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)

Basically you can create an umbrella project which define a set of common configurations by creating a gradle.build file and a gradle.settings file.
The build file contains the properties, dependencies and plugins commons to all projects, the settings.gradle defines what subprojects inherits those configurations.

Moreover, to have an idea of the gradle plugin ecosystem you could check [this](http://wiki.gradle.org/display/GRADLE/Plugins) source.

Comment: Not really looking for multi-project builds. As mentioned earlier I am looking for some kind of inheritance. e.g. most jboss/apache maven projects inherit a common pom. Then the common pom can be improved over time and new versions of it can be released. Some guidelines or rules can be put in there.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible, if you want the parent to be cached locally and stored in a Maven repository.

I have added feature request here:
http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/support_for_gradle_parent_shared_between_projects_cached_locally