# Super POM, Parent POM type of hierarchy management in Gradle

Tags: gradle

We are currently using Maven as our build tool and there is a directive to migrate to Gradle. Our current setup is:

1. We have a super POM that defines all third party dependencies, various plugins, distributionManagement URLs and this POM is uploaded to our releases repo.
2. We have an aggregator POM that uses this super POM as parent and aggregates several submodules.
3. We have several profiles defined in aggregator POM to build components.

My question is, what is the best way to do all these in Gradle. How can I define all third party dependencies in a single Gradle config and use it in other places.

I am new to Gradle and so, this might sound a very stupid question. But I request all to provide some help and guidance.

Comment: what was the main reason for a maven to gradle migration? how did it go?

Comment: @Gevorg, one of the main reason why we wanted to use gradle is more control on build steps. With maven, we would have to write plugins, with gradle those are just simple groovy scripts. This parent/aggregator POM was an initial need, but as the architecture/design of components evolved (for the migrated app), we felt lesser need of such a feature. Overall, it went smooth. But I feel such a migration complexity varies from app to app.

Answer (score 10):

I do the following:

- Define a gradle script (something like a parent pom)
- Apply it (something like extending) in my build.gradle file

  `apply from: 'https://youUrlHere/parent.gradle'`

For more info, you can have a look here: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/inheriting_from_a_parent_not_in_the_same_project

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you push your build script to a repository to be able to download it later. Is that like a file server? Isn't there a mechanism similar to `maven deploy`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the super POM, you'd write a Gradle plugin and distribute that. Not exactly sure what you get out of 2. and 3., but if these definitions are reused between builds, they would again go into a plugin, and otherwise into a parent build script.

Comment: How (1) is possible without plugin; in maven I just define a parent pom and upload to my releases repo and refer that in other POMs? (2) is same as multi-module project from which I have to generate several components (webApp.war, soap-api.war etc). In maven to achieve this, I define profiles (webApp profile to include module-1, module-3; api profile to include module-1, 2, 5 etc); what is equivalent of that in Gradle? I didn't find anything in documentation of Gradle. Gradle `include` does not allow this flexibility from a central place.

Comment: You can upload a build script to a web server, but that has some drawbacks over writing a binary plugin (build will fail if web server is down). The "equivalent" to Maven profiles is an if-statement in your build script, but it's rarely needed.

Comment: Peter, I am trying to understand your point of views. Since I am new to Gradle, I carry Maven mindset and am trying to bend Gradle to fit Maven philosophies. However, I don't want that. Could you please help me finding the best way to design build aspect for my kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the Parent pom content in to Gradle init file very easily.

You need to take

- repository,
- distribution management
- profiling
- other checks like findbugs, checkstyle etc

in to init script.

The detail is huge, You can find complete information here by me.

http://www.scmtechblog.net/2015/12/how-to-migrate-parent-pom-from-maven-to.html