# Gradle company parent

Tags: java, android, gradle

Like in Maven we can define a global company POM, that can be used for all the projects.

How does this works in Gradle?

I want to define one global parent that can be used for all the upcoming projects, but I don't know how to complete this with Gradle. I was reading the documentation but that is only talking about project/parent style and not a global one.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having your projects "inherit" from a common parent you would typically encapsulate common login info a [Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html) and apply the plugin to all your projects.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to the already answered question [gradle parent pom like feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468109/gradle-parent-pom-like-feature). I would like to point out what has changed in Gradle since then.

Gradle has no concept which is directly comparable to Mavens parent POM construct. It is true that custom Gradle plugins can be used to apply company defaults to projects built by Gradle. I found a good [Blog Post](http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/2014/12/gradle-and-the-parent-pom/) describing this in detail.

But Gradle goes beyond that. Gradle has [Initialization Scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) which are used to share build logic across projects within the company. The script below for example, `manifest_defaults.gradle`, can be used to add default `MANIFEST` entries to jar files produced by Java based project builds:

```
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.plugins.hasPlugin('java')) {
            project.jar {
                manifest {
                    attributes {
                        "Implementation-Title": project.archivesBaseName,
                        "Implementation-Vendor": "My Company"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Init scripts in the enterprise are best used in conjunction with customized [company Gradle distributions](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2012/10/gradle-goodness-distribute-custom.html). Combining this with the [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) is a powerful feature.