# How to implement a Maven base pom file concept using Gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle

In Maven one can use the base pom file concept(https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/maven_in_our_development_proce_3)  - the file everyone would then reuse

Is it a similar concept in Gradle? We use Gradle to build Java projects

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15472364/2003986)

Basically, the parent project can hold the role of "parent POM" and thanks to Gradle's `allprojects`, `subprojects` and extra properties mechanisms, you can reproduce Maven's main behavior. Also you can split your configuration in several `.gradle` files and include them with `apply from`. Finally, regular and custom plugins can be defined in the parent project, for target or all sub-projects.